# How to use the sv operator together with the _T macro in Visual C/C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, unicode-literals

I want to define a `string_view` literal using the `sv` operator, but since my application can be compiled as either ANSI or UNICODE I use Microsoft's `_T` macro from `tchar.h`.

Since I want to apply the `sv` operator on a `wchar_t` pointer/string I assumed I had to write this:

```
using namespace std::literals;
constexpr static auto H1{_T("hello")sv};
```

But this does not compile and gives the following errors:

```
error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'sv'
error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '}'
error C2059: syntax error: '}'
```

However, when I write this, it compiles and works correctly:

```
using namespace std::literals;
constexpr static auto H2{_T("hello"sv)};
```

The first alternative seems more logical to me since the second alternative looks like the `sv` operator is applied on a `char`-pointer/string, while actually it is being applied on a Unicode string (if I compile in Unicode using the `/D_UNICODE` option).

Strange thing is that if I try to compile the following code:

```
using namespace std::literals;
constexpr static auto H1{_T("hello")sv};
constexpr static auto H2{_T("hello"sv)};
constexpr static auto H3{L"hello"sv};
```

then the first line does not compile, as explained above.  But when I add the `/EP` option to the compiler (so I get a file with the output of the preprocessor), I see the preprocessor translates these lines to this:

```
using namespace std::literals;
constexpr static auto H1{L"hello"sv};
constexpr static auto H2{L"hello"sv};
constexpr static auto H3{L"hello"sv};
```

And compiling this output succeeds.

So preprocessing-only and then compiling works.  Compiling in one go, doesn't.

Is there anything in the C++ standard that forbids me to use the first alternative (which seems more logical to me)?  If not, is this a bug in Microsofts compiler?

Comment: As a workaround you can use `constexpr static std::string_view H1{_T("hello")}` instead

Comment: Note that data inside a macro and data outside can never combine into a single token, not even with the token-pasting operator (`##`).  The file resulting from preprocessing doesn't show the token boundaries, which are different between the first and latter cases

Comment: Furthermore, consider why the definition of `_T(str)` is `L##str` and not simply `L str`

Comment: @Ben, then why does the preprocessor (using the /EP option) generate the correct, expected output, but when preprocessing-and-compiling in one go doesn't compile this?

Comment: @Patrick: I repeat, **The file resulting from preprocessing doesn't show the token boundaries**.  They are lost by writing the preprocessor result out to text and then reading it in again.